# what does this exception mean >First-chance exceptionUnhandled exception at 0x000007FEFD38A06D in Project3.exe

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

I am working on automatic number plate recognition where I am providing image of a car as input but I am getting this exception

> First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD38A06D in Project3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000000000249160.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

If I choose continue option I am getting

> Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD38A06D in Project3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000002590D0.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

If I select continue option further I get

> Debug assertion failed Line 1140 Expression:vector script out of range

Can anybody tell what does all these error mean?

Comment: It means you need to debug your program.  When the exception occurs when debugging, open the call stack window and trace back into you code.

Comment: You clearly have a problem at line 1140

Comment: Please paste code around line 1140.

Comment: *Debug assertion failed Line 1140 Expression:vector script out of range* -- So you're saying you have no idea what the error may be telling you?

Comment: *vector script out of range* - probably means that you index variable to a `std::vector` object is beyond the number of elements or beyond the capacity of the vector.

Answer (score 3):

> First-chance exception at 0x000007FEFD38A06D in Project3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x0000000000249160.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Let's break this down:

- [*First-chance exception*](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidklinems/2005/07/12/what-is-a-first-chance-exception/): This is the debugger telling you that an exception has been thrown. It is not an error. If you decide to continue, the exception will be passed to the program.
- *0x000007FEFD38A06D in Project3.exe*: this is where the [instruction pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) was when the exception was thrown. It is not very useful to you, but it can sometimes be used to figure out where a problem happened in a build that has no symbols.
- *Microsoft C++ exception*: This was a C++ exception, as opposed to something like [a Structured Exception](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680657(v=vs.85).aspx).
- *cv::Exception*: This is the name of the exception that was thrown. Looks like it's an [exception from OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d1/dee/classcv_1_1Exception.html).
- *at memory location 0x0000000000249160*: This is the address of the exception object on the stack. Again, not very useful.

Pressing *Continue* will then pass the exception to the program. If it is caught properly, the program can continue executing normally. If there is no handler for this exception, you get the next message:

> Unhandled exception at at 0x000007FEFD38A06D in Project3.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x00000000002590D0.
>   If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

This means that an exception was thrown, but there's no catch handler for it anywhere. This is most likely a programming error, probably on your part. It looks like you called an OpenCV function which failed by throwing a `cv::Exception`, but you're not catching it.

This would normally lead to a crash, but since you're running inside a debugger, you get the option to *ignore* this exception. That's what the *Continue* button will do on this dialog. So instead of throwing an exception, the code will just continue executing as if nothing had happened. This is likely to fail eventually, as an error condition has now been ignored.

> Debug assertion failed Line 1140 Expression:vector script out of range

There. I don't know in which file this happened, but somewhere on a line 1140 an `std::vector` was indexed with a value that was out of range. This is unsurprising since you ignored the exception and allowed the program to continue.

Long story short: you need to catch `cv::Exception` and handle error conditions properly.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. Next time will keep in mind to do bit more research .